# Is there any way to assign a keyboard button to control in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a calculator on c# Winform, it has buttons for numeric value input. I want buttons click operation to be performed by a keyboard key press. Like when I press "1" on the keyboard it processes the click operation of the "button1".

I have tried

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
            {
               button1.PerformClick();
            }
        }
```

But it has no effect on my program.

Comment: Why do you test for `e.Control`?

Comment: See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50920.c-implementing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-form-application.aspx

Comment: Remove `e.Control`. The [Keys.NumPadX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=net-5.0) values are sequential which means you can get the numeric value by subtracting `NumPad0` from `KeyCode` provided it is between `NumPad0` and `NumPad9`, eg : `if (e.KeyCode>=Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode<=Keys.NumPad9){ var number=e.KeyCode-Keys.NumPad0;}`

Comment: The keydown function is not selected in the Form Event Properties for KeyDown, that's why it was not working. Now it is fine but still I am not able to assign the ENTER key to my "equal" button. I have tried using the form acceptbutton and the keys.enter but they don't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
        {
           button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```